# Python - splitting string into list based on dict tuple value

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a tuple dict. Im matching the first tuple value within a string. If the value is met I would like to add this value and also the next amount of chars to  a based on the second tuple, as a single entry to a list

```
data = 60806122225212888810

Dict = {'STOP' : ('60', 2), 'ADD' : ('61', 4), 'MUL' : ('52', 0), 'SUB' : ('10', 0), 'START' : ('12', 4)}
```

my desired output is a list of ['6080', '612222', '52', '128888', '10']`

This is my current code:

```
 while i<len(data):
    if data [i:i+2] in Opcodes_Dict[item][0]:
        L.append(data[i:i+Opcodes_Dict[item][1]])
        i+=Opcodes_Dict[item][1]
    else:
      L.append(data[i:i+2])
      i+=2
 print(L)
```

Im sorry if this is hard to understand, Im very stuck

Comment: For the second item in the desired output why don't you have `'612222'`?

Comment: Also, does the key value not matter?

Comment: sorry I do need it as 612222, I will re-edit

Comment: key does not matter no

Comment: Also, `dict` objects are not ordered. Do you mean to use ordereddict? If not, do you want the program to be able to look back? For example, would `11221133` and `{'key':('11', 2), 'key2':('11',2)}` return `['1122', '1122']` or `['1122','1133']`?

Comment: @UnsignedByte OP's code is walking the string, not iterating the dictionary, so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the key doesn't matter, make a dict with just the opcode and the value.  In your loop, test if the opcode is in this new dict, and slice accordingly:

```
data = '60806122225212888810'

Dict = {'STOP' : ('60', 2), 'ADD' : ('61', 4), 'MUL' : ('52', 0), 'SUB' : ('10', 0), 'START' : ('12', 4)}

Opcodes_Dict = {a:b for k,(a,b) in Dict.items()}

i = 0
L = []
while i < len(data):
    op = data[i:i+2]
    if op in Opcodes_Dict:
        value = Opcodes_Dict[op]
        L.append(data[i:i + 2 + value])
        i += 2 + value
    else:
        L.append(op)
        i += 2
print(L)
```

Output:

```
['6080', '612222', '52', '128888', '10']
```

Comment: Python Dictionaries are not ordered!

Comment: @UnsignedByte It's not relying on the order.  The OP's code was grabbing two characters at a time and then looking it up.  Mix up the dictionary and you'll get the same result with this code.

Comment: @UnsignedByte And FYI, Python 3.6 maintains insertion order by implementation, and Python 3.7 guarantees it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Sorry, I wasn't really sure what the question was asking.